# Returning int, int* and int& from a function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, reinterpret-cast

I just wanted to clarify something, imagine we have the function signature:

1) `int* X(){}`

2) `int Y(){}`

3) `int& Z(){}`

I am trying to work out the exhaustive possibilities of types of values I can return for the above. The below show possible implementations for the above function bodies:

1)

```
int* X(){
    int* b = new int(6);
    return b;
}
```

2)

```
int Y(){
    int b = 6;
    return b;
}
```

or

```
int Y(){
    int* b = new int(6);
    return *b;
}
```

**EDIT: 2) not good because of memory leak if b isn't deleted.**

3)

```
int& Z(){
    int b = 6;
    return b;
}
```

**EDIT: 3) not good because b will go out of scope once function returns.**

Is there anything I have missed out which could be returned from any of the above 3 function signatures? Getting a bit more adventurous, what about:

```
int* X(){
    int b = 6;
    return reinterpret_cast<b>;
}
```

and

```
int X(){
    int* b = new int(6);
    return reinterpret_cast<b>;
}
```

? (My understanding of `reinterpret_cast` may be wrong...)

Comment: Can't wait to hear the justifications for the down-voting (if there are any)....

Comment: The second part of 2 should be `return ( *b );`
3 may be incorrect. You are returning reference to something that may not exist (it is volatile).

Comment: Z won't work out very well.

Comment: there are infinite possibilities of types of values you can return, you can return int *************** until the compiler give up.

Comment: @chris because the local variable would have been removed from the stack- cool.

Comment: @yngum I think you know what I am trying to get at though...

Comment: @user997112 The problem with your question is that there are literally an infinite number of expressions that could be used to return an object. The only fact is, you have to return an object of the return type.

Comment: People will downvote if they do not like something.  Wish stackexchange introduces a policy to justify downvotes.

Comment: i'd say SO is a question & answers forum but no teaching book ... this isn't a fit for Q&A IMO

Comment: @unxnut +1. that'd be great -- down voting without even a comment is just plain wrong

Comment: Can someone comment on my usage of reinterpret_cast? Is it correct?

Comment: No, your `reinterpret_cast` won't even compile. [Reference here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int Y(){
    int* b = new int(6);
    return b*;
}
```

This has a syntax error. To dereference `b`, you would do `*b`. Nonetheless, this is a very bad implementation because it leaks memory. The dynamically allocated `int` will never be destroyed.

```
int& Z(){
    int b = 6;
    return b;
}
```

This is also bad because you are returning a reference to a local variable. The local variable `b` will be destroyed when the function returns and you'll be left with a reference to a non-existent object.

Answer (score 0):

1. `int* X(){}`

when you have to return address which is pointing to integer

2. `int Y(){}`

for returning simple integer

3. `int& Z(){}`

this is something different,
you don't have any argument in `Z()` thus it is useless.
It must be like

```
int& Z(int &a)
{
    //code body
    return (a);
}
```

and return this to reference variable